# How to read an empty csv file and convert into an excel.?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, read.csv

I have 3 csv files in folder and iterate through each file and convert each file into xlsx sheet.One of the csv file was 0kb(Empty file).
My Code :

```
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
 df=pd.read_csv(file)
 df.to_excel(file+".xlsx",sheet_name=file,index=False)
```

Error : `No columns to parse from the file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this by catching the exception that occurs when the file is empty, and creating an empty dataframe to output to the Excel file in that case.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    df.to_excel(file+".xlsx", sheet_name=file, index=False)
```

Comment: I think it makes a single xlsx file.i need to do 3 xlsx files(if folder contains 3 csv files,i need 3 xlsx sheet)..I tested this lines Thanks @joanis

Comment: When I tested this, it created one output xlsx file per input csv file, just like your code did.

Comment: Sorry Joans..Checked once again with empty filees,it worked the way i expect.Thanks